# Bootstrap - custom flash/alert boxes

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Rails` app in which I use `Boosttrap` and `HAML`, when I present the flash messages I would like to change their appearance slightly. I want them to be full screen with `cold-md-1` margins on each side, and a `col-md-10` contains the flash message.

What I've tried is:

```
- if flash[:notice]

  / Full width is a css class with 100% width, so the width works...
  .alert.alert-info.alert-dismissable.full-width
    .col-md-1
    %button{:type => "button", :class => "close", 'data-dismiss' => "alert", 'aria-   hidden' => "true"} &times;
    = flash[:notice]
    .col-md-1
```

This doesn't work quite as I want (not the correct margins). I have also tried to contain the flash message like this:

```
.col-md-1
.col-md-10
  [message]
.col-md-1
```

Then it looks ok, but the close button doesn't work as I want (it doesn't close the whole message). To illustrate what I what to achieve, see the image below:

[image]

Here I want the close button (**note:** only the close button, and not the background) to align with the `account` drop down and the gray box.

Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using some javascript (or coffee-script). View:

```
.alert.alert-info.alert-dismissable.no-border-radius
  .container
    .col-md-1
    .col-md-10
      = flash[:notice]
      %button{:type => "button", :class => "close", 'data-dismiss' => "alert", 'aria-hidden' => "true"} &times;
    .col-md-1
```

JavaScript (or CoffeeScript):

```
$('.close').click ->
  $(".alert").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making simple thing look complex. *You want to have col-md-1 margin on each side so your **alerts width will be col-md-10** and **bootstrap3 has [`col-md-offset-*`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) classes for offsetting it.***

```
- if flash[:notice]
  .alert.alert-info.alert-dismissable.col-md-10.col-md-offset-1
    .col-md-1
    // give proper width and margin to this div to align button with dropdown
      %button{:type => "button", :class => "close", 'data-dismiss' => "alert", 'aria-   hidden' => "true"} &times;
    = flash[:notice]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but It doesn't result in the effect I want. The notice box isn't full-screen any more. I only want the content of the message (the `x` button in the example above) to align with the other content of my page, not the blue background color.

Comment: @Anders your question said `I want them to be full screen with cold-md-1 margins on each side` if there will be col-md-1 margin on each side then you'll be left with col-md-10 only :). Can you explain which one is your notice div and with which you want to align your x button

Comment: I have updated my question now. Hope it's more clear.

Comment: @Anders what is the width of account dropdown? Just use a container outside your button to align it with dropdown

Comment: I have tried that, but not got it to work perfectly. The width/x alignment changes since I use Bootstrap there as well, the same structure, `col-md-1` `col-md-10` `[content, like the account button]` `col-md-1`. So the left & right sizes/margins changes based on resolution.And I want the flash message to behave the same way...

Comment: @Anders It's difficult to give you a proper solution like this, can you make a fiddle where i can edit your code?

Comment: @Anders If you want both of them to behave same way then why not add both of them inside a wrapper and then divide them individually?

Comment: I don't see how that would make any difference, since I've tried to contain them the same way already. If possible I would like this close action/button to work with the following structure: `.col-md-1
.col-md-10
  [message]
.col-md-1`, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @Anders you can customize its position for tablet and mobile using proper classes like col-sm-* and col-xs-* but for in between screen there is very less you can do unless they are contained inside same parent and have width 100% of that parent so that they both behave in same way when there parent is resized

Comment: @Anders you can customize its position for tablet and mobile using proper classes like col-sm-* and col-xs-* but for in between screen there is very less you can do unless they are contained inside same parent and have width 100% of that parent so that they both behave in same way when there parent is resized

Comment: I solved it by using some quite simple JavaScript, see my answer below. Thanks anyway!